# Processing a tree in F# using continuations

Tags: lambda, f#, continuations

I'm trying to understand how continuations work, I have this example that I came across in the book, *Real World Functional Programming* by Tomas Petricek with Jon Skeet. But this really has got my head spinning so I must ask for some detailed help..

```
type IntTree = 
    | Leaf of int
    | Node of IntTree * IntTree

let rec sumTreeCont tree cont =
  match tree with
  | Leaf(n) -> cont(n)
  | Node(left, right) -> 
      sumTreeCont left (fun leftSum ->
        sumTreeCont right (fun rightSum ->
          cont(leftSum + rightSum)))
```

Okay here's what I have been able to figure out myself... In the second branch we first process the left side of the node and pass a lambda. This lambda will instantiate a closure class with two fields, `right: IntTree` and `cont: (int -> 'a)` which will be invoked by the base case. But then it also seems that the "inner lambda" captures `leftSum` but I don't quite understand how it all fits together, I have to admit that I get a bit dizzy when I try to figure this out.

Comment: I highly recommend reading Brian McNamara's blog series on catamorphisms (which includes continuations) https://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/?s=catamorphism

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think Christian's answer is a good one - continuation passing style is really just a (not so) simple mechanical transformation that you do on the original source code. This might be easier to see when you do it step by step:

1) Start with the original code (here, I change the code to only do one operation per line):

```
let rec sumTree tree =
   match tree with
   | Leaf(n) -> n
   | Node(left, right) -> 
       let leftSum = sumTree left
       let rightSum = sumTree right
       leftSum + rightSum
```

2) Add continuation parameter and call it instead of returning the result (this is still not tail-recursive). To make this type-check, I added continuation `fun x -> x` to both sub-calls so that they just return the sum as the result:

```
let rec sumTree tree cont =
   match tree with
   | Leaf(n) -> cont n
   | Node(left, right) -> 
       let leftSum = sumTree left (fun x -> x)
       let rightSum = sumTree right (fun x -> x)
       cont (leftSum + rightSum)
```

3) Now, let's change the first recursive call to use continuation passing style - lift the rest of the body into the continuation:

```
let rec sumTree tree cont =
   match tree with
   | Leaf(n) -> cont n
   | Node(left, right) -> 
       sumTree left (fun leftSum ->
         let rightSum = sumTree right (fun x -> x)
         cont (leftSum + rightSum) )
```

4) And repeat the same thing for the second recursive call:

```
let rec sumTree tree cont =
   match tree with
   | Leaf(n) -> cont n
   | Node(left, right) -> 
       sumTree left (fun leftSum ->
         sumTree right (fun rightSum -> 
           cont (leftSum + rightSum) ))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification! I think your book has been excellent thus far, but the concept of continuations just seems to take a little while for me to grasp :).

Comment: Great answer. Obviously the transformation of step 2) needs to be applied to all cases of the DU: `| Leaf(n) -> cont n`

Answer (score 7):

It might be easier to grok if you first consider this expression for calculating the sum of a tree:

```
let rec sumTree tree =
   match tree with
   | Leaf(n) -> n
   | Node(left, right) -> 
       sumTree left + sumTree right
```

The problem with this solution is that it overflows the stack for large trees due to excessive stack frame allocations. The solution is to use make sure the recursive call is in tail position meaning you can't perform any operation after the call (in the case above, addition is performed after the recursive calls). In this case the compiler can eliminate unnecessary stack frames and thus avoid overflow. The technique for solving this is to use continuation passing style as in Tomas' and Jon's solution. As you can see, the continuations used here make sure that no operations are performed after the recursive calls.

Answer (score 5):

I made a Visio drawing in the process of trying to understand this, I figured I might share it here in case it helps someone else. I realize it might just end up being more confusing for some but for visual learners (like me) I feel like it made things clearer drawing an example of how it might look to process a tree like this.

[image: Processing tree with continuations an illustrative example]